# Fantasy novel, magic sword and different worlds

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I am looking for some help remembering this book series I listened to on audiobook many years ago. It was a good story I just for the life of me can't remember the name, author or any of the character names lol I think this is a long shot as I don't remember many details but I really would like to read it again.

Some of the details I do remember: the story is set in a medieval time, not on this planet.

It's told from the viewpoint of a man, I believe he was a soldier. The main character meets him in a war torn world and allows him to travel with her.

The main character is a woman. She is a wanderer and carries a sword that only she can hold. If I remember correctly the magic is too powerful for anyone else to bear and it physically hurts them.

This sword allows her to pass through portals into other worlds. The portals are stationary and they need to travel to them.

There was also something special about her horse.... Ugh.

Each book is set on a different world.I only remember two of the worlds.

One is doomed world. It's land is sinking and towards the end there is a rush to get to the next portal. The book is set in a bog filled environment.

The other world I remember is more lush. Open plains and dense forest. The man is separated from the woman for some time. He stays with tribes-people, elves maybe? When it's time for them to go to the next world the man is torn between staying with his new friends and leaving.

So that's really all I remember. At the time I remember noting after I had read a few of the books that the author never really finished the series.

Any help would be appreciated :) throw me some guesses so I can do some research!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[The Chronicles of Morgaine](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40819-the-morgaine-cycle)** by **C J Cherryh**

Morgaine

1. Gate of Ivrel (1976)
2. Well of Shiuan (1978)
3. Fires of Azeroth (1979)
4. Exile's Gate (1988)

Chronicles of Morgaine (omnibus) (1985)

The Morgaine Saga (omnibus) (2000)

The Complete Morgaine (omnibus) (2015)

Comment: Definitely.  Morgaine is tasked with closing the portals which link both time and space.  Careless use of the portals for time travel had previously caused catastrophic damage to the fabric of reality.  Morgain travels from world to world closing the portals behind her.  Her sword, Changeling, is not actually a sword at all (though it is constantly mistake as such) and creates (from what I recall) some sort of mini-wormhole.

Comment: I remember reading the first two books, it was kinda boring.

Comment: The sword Changling does exactly the same thing as the gates and opens a wormhole, but unlike the gates the wormhole it opens up has no fixed destination, so bye bye